# void (refresh) won't refresh

Tags: nsxmlparser

I have an iPhone app that uses the method

```
- (void)refresh
{
    self.title = @"Refreshing...";
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.5;
    [self.dataController parse];
}
```

to refresh and reparse.

The problem is that when I tap the refresh button on the navigationBar, the program just freezes and does not refresh the data. The app pulls data from RSS and pushes it into a tableViewController.

Here's the code for the barButtonItem

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(refresh)];
```

Here's the parse method:

```
- (void) parse
{
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://www.baylornotes.org/rss/articles/all"]
}


-(void) parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:feedURL];

    [parser setDelegate:self];

    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

}
```

Help!

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `[self.dataController parse];` Does it get there? If it does, and then "freezes" after that point, then the problem lies in the `parse` method, which is code you havent posted.

Comment: I put a breakpoint there, and it does get there.
I'm going to post the parse method in the question.